# Issues when dynamically rendering content with form validations in php web-app

Tags: php, html, web-applications

I have a php web-app where I render dynamic content. I have a base template file which displays content according to the passed parameter. Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>  </title>
        <?php include("head.php");?>

    </head>

    <body>
        <?php

            $selected_category = $_GET['category'];

            include("navbar.php");

            include("$selected_category.php");

            include("footer.php");

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I pass multiple web pages to dynamically generate formatted views. This works well for most of the content. Issue arises when implementing form validations. My login code is as below :

```
<section class="my-5 jumbotron">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="py-5 text-center">
            
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
</div>
        <?php 
        if(!empty($login_err)){
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">' . $login_err . '</div>';
        }        
        ?>
<div class="w-50 m-auto ">
    
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars("login.php"); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>">
                <span class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="dynamiccontent.php?category=register">Sign up now</a>.</p>
            <p>Have an Okta login ? <a href="oktaauth.php">Proceed</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This renders well with the dynamic template when form inputs are validated successfully. When there is an invalid input, just the login code is rendered and not the dynamically formatted content along with the validation error.[image: Dynamically rendered page]
[image: Rendered when form validation is triggered]

How do I make sure my form validations show up on the same dynamically generated page. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Shouldn't you submit your form to `dynamiccontent.php?category=login` instead of directly to `login.php`? _Side note:_ You don't need to wrap the URL in `htmlspecialchards()` if you're using hard coded URL's since you know that it doesn't contain anything that needs to be encoded.

Comment: A warning. Don't just accept and trust that the `category` parameter contains a valid file name (or that it even exist). Someone could basically make your code include what ever php file they want this way. Always validate the user data you get. Add a list of allowed pages/file names and throw a 404 of someone enters something that's not in that list.